# How do I average a column of values while excluding rows that contain a certain value from another column? PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to write a code for a data table in Power BI that averages values of a table but categorizes them based on ID and Project but at the same time exclude a value from another column. Below is what I am trying to accomplish and column `AVG` is the goal. Excluding `Type = "II"` and averaging the values based on category columns `[ID]` and `[Project]`.

[image]

Below is the code I am working on but it is incorrect. What would be the best solution?

```
AVG =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGEX ( FILTER ( Table, Table[Type] <> "II" ), Table[Values] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[ID], 'Table'[Project] )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
AVG =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( Table[Values] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table, Table[ID], Table[Project] ),
    Table[Type] <> "II"
)
```

I don't see a reason to use an iterator function (`AVERAGEX`) and a simple Boolean filter  should work how you want (instead of using `FILTER`).